# Application of Arzela-Ascoli Theorem

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

I have the following problem: Let's consider a sequence of functions $\{f_n\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\subset C^1(\mathbb{R})$ such that both $\{f_n\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ and $\{f_n'\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ are uniformly bounded sequences and for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$, $f_n$ and $f_n'$ are Lipschitz with the same constants $K_1,K_2$ respectively. Therefore, by Arzela-Ascoli's Theorem there exist functions $g,h\in C(\mathbb{R})$ such that $$
f_n\to g \quad \hbox{and} \quad f_n'\to h \quad \hbox{uniformly}.
$$
My question is, under what conditions we can conclude that $g'=h$, or is this for free?

**Edit:** Sorry, I actually wanted to ask another more specific question (in some sense related). Let us consider a sequence of functions $\{f_n\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}=\{f(\cdot+n)-f(n)\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$, where $f\in C^1(\mathbb{R})$ is such that $\{f_n\}$ is a uniformly bounded sequence of Lipschitz functions (be careful, now $f$ is not necesarily Lipschitz, but $f_n$ is). On the other hand, let's suppose that $\{g_n\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}=\{f'(\cdot+n)\}$ is a uniformly bounded sequence formed by Lipschitz functions. Therefore, by Arzela-Ascoli's Theorem we have $$
f_n\to g \quad \hbox{and}\quad f_n'\to h.
$$
My question again is, under what conditions $g'=h$. Sorry for the mistake in the first question.

Comment: In the second edit, are the $g_n$-s an equicontinuous family? Also, I would assume that $f_n\to g$ and stuff means that *there is a subsequence* $f_{n_k}\to g$ and so on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is for free! $f_n(x)-f_n(0)=\int_0^{x} f_n'(t) dt$ and taking limits we get $g(x)-g(0)=\int_0^{x} h(t) dt$. Since $h$ is continuous this implies that $g$ is differentiable and $g'=h$.

Comment: Sorry, I actually wanted to ask another question. I edited my previous question, but I think the solution is similar, right?

Comment: @Sharik My proof has nothing to do with Lipschitz conidition, etc. If $f_n \to g$ uniformly and $f_n' \to h$ uniformly then $g'=h$

Answer (score 0):

> It is a general fact that if $I$ is a bounded interval,  $\{f_n\}_{n\in\Bbb N}$ is a sequence of differentiable functions, there is a point $p\in I$ such that $f_n(p)$ converges, and $\{f'_n\}_{n\in\Bbb N}$ converges uniformly on $I$ to some function $u$, then $\{f_n\}_{n\in\Bbb N}$ converges uniformly on $I$ to a function $f$ such that $f'=u$. Immediate consequence is that if $I$ is not bounded the same conclusion holds with uniform convergence *on compact sets*.

The proof of this is a bit lengthy to write down, but it is not particularly difficult: it's analysis 1 material, and it basically revolves around tricky, repeated use of Lagrange's theorem. The result holds regardless of regularity of derivatives.

Some passages of your question are not too clear to me. However, it seems to me that your needs fall under that theorem.